# How do I see the commands issued by cmake with --build option

Tags: build, cmake

How could I see the commands issued when I run "cmake --build . --target INSTALL" command? There doesn't seem to be an option like --versbose or something. The cmake help says that "cmake --build" is an interface to the underlying build tool, but doesn't say anything about the dump of commands issued.

The reason I need this is because, when I try to run msbuild on commandline, it fails with an error saying the target INSTALL doesn't exist in the project. However, cmake succeeds. So, I guess, cmake also might be using msbuild itself, albeit with some specific options.

Comment: I am amazed that there is no answer for presumably such a simple thing.. :(

Answer (score 13):

You can pass additional options to the native build tool with the `--` switch, i.e.:

```
cmake --build . --target INSTALL -- /verbosity:detailed
```

Comment: Actually, I would like to see the commandline issued by cmake e.g. "msbuild product.sln /t:ALL_BUILD". I am not interested in finding what msbuild is doing in this case. So, the verbosity is required for cmake itself.

Comment: `cmake --build ... -- -clp:ShowCommandLine` (see MSBuild [command-line reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-command-line-reference?view=vs-2019)).

Answer (score 2):

you can found the solution at:

https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_FAQ

On Windows (nmake) you can override CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE by using
nmake /S
If you actually want to see what the command looks like, set CMAKE_START_TEMP_FILE and CMAKE_END_TEMP_FILE to "" -- be warned, however, you cannot set these as variables on the CMake command line with -D. Instead, see the very bottom of the file "Modules/Platform/Windows.cmake" and uncomment the lines that set these variables to the empty string.