# How to build with CMake to both release config and verbose

Tags: cmake, verbose

I am trying to build with CMake and to pass both options: config: Release and `VERBOSE=ON`:

```
cmake --build . --config Release -- VERBOSE=ON
```

And in CMake of Visual I have the switch:

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 14 2015"
-DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE:BOOL=ON ^
```

if I pass only '--config Release' it works.

Now it's failing with this message:

```
15:40:51 MSBUILD : error MSB1008: Only one project can be specified.
15:40:51 Switch: VERBOSE=1
15:40:51 
15:40:51 For switch syntax, type "MSBuild /help"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`VERBOSE=ON` is not understood by MSBuild.

You probably know that syntax from Unix Makefile generators, where setting eg. the `VERBOSE` environment variable will give you the verbose output. Note that this is a feature of the generator (ie. `make`) and not of CMake. Thus when switching to a different generator (in this case MSBuild), you have to find a different way to get the verbose output that works with that generator.

For MSBuild, that would be [the `/verbosity` option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-command-line-reference). See also [this answer for details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21172053/577603).

As for the [`CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/variable/CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE.html) option, the manual clearly states that this option only has an effect for Makefile generators (emphasis added by me):

> Users may enable the option in their local build tree to get more
>   verbose output *from Makefile builds* and show each command line as it
>   is launched.

Comment: as @bbv said in  "this answer for details.", this is showing how to see more details of the "msbuild product.sln /t:ALL_BUILD". I am not interested in finding what msbuild is doing in this case. So, the verbosity is required for cmake itself. 
thanks